# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebDriver API

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I downloaded the selenium-java-2.0a5.zip

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

and ran the following code:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

but then I got

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.example.Example.main(Example.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Did I miss a step ? I made sure to import the **selenium-java-2.0a5.jar** into the project.

Comment: check my answer. you forgot to add HtmlUnit's jar to classpath.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

htmlunit jar is not in the classpath. Include dependency lib jars of selenium-java-2.0a5.jar as well. I am sure they must have been provided in the zip you downloaded

Answer (score 2):

You seem to use **"HtmlUnit"** in your project and its jar is missing from classpath.
Add it to your project properties as you added selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You want to download `selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar` from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list instead, as this includes dependencies.