# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener when using HTMLUnitDriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use HTMLUnitDriver in my selenium test to understand how HTMLUnitDriver works.  Kindly help me with resolving the issue.

I have added the below jars to the build path in eclipse
selenium-java-2.53.0 jars
TestNG jar

Added the below jars as these were mentioned in other posts as a solution to the error I encountered. However, the issue remains.

selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.52.0 jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleSearch {
    
    @Test
    public void testHTMLUnitDriver() {
        
        HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
                    
        unitDriver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
        
        System.out.println("Title of the page is:" +unitDriver.getTitle()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: TestNG Trace is as given below:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener
 at GoogleSearch.testHTMLUnitDriver(GoogleSearch.java:13)

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your code as code and add the error message to the original question and properly format it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebDriver API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499847/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-webdriver-api)

Answer (score 4):

You don't only need the HtmlUnitDriver in your classpath, you also need HtmlUnit itself in the classpath. These are not the same thing. HtmlUnitDriver is the selenium driver that can talk to the HtmlUnit headless browser. Download from here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I added all the libraries under lib folder of htmlunit-2.22 and executed my code. I encountered the error  in  TestNG trace -   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver

Answer (score 0):

You need to add htmlunit-cssparser as dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-cssparser</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```