# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium

Ok guys, I've been trying for about an hour to resolve this error that I'm getting and no dice.

This is the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
>          at com.painlessshopping.mohamed.findit.MarksSearch$fetcher.doInBackground(MarksSearch.java:167)
>          at com.painlessshopping.mohamed.findit.MarksSearch$fetcher.doInBackground(MarksSearch.java:126)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

It is a NoClassDefFoundError meaning (at least to my knowledge) that one of the dependencies is messed up. However, upon going into project structure the file dependency is there, aswell as the

```
compile files('libs/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.9.0.jar')
```

line in the app build.gradle file. So what's up?

the specific selenium library that im using in conjunction with this is: 
selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar

If that has any relevance whatsoever.

Edit: Here is what my Project Structure Dependency Tab Looks Like:
[image: Project Structure]

Any help is appreciated, frustration level is high :'(

Comment: I think this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499847/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-webdriver-api

Comment: This error usually appears if you do not add the required classpaths files during compile time. Go to `Project-structure` select your app under the `module` tab and to the right under the `dependencies` tab will list the jars that are being compiled with your program.

Comment: Yes, your program is looking for that jar file or class in the jar file and it is not in your class path.

Comment: @coletrain But as I said there is already a file dependency there? Should I change it to a different type of dependency ? Please see the most recent edit

Comment: @YamahaT64312 the last thing I could think of is make sure all of your classes are included within the package of your android application. If not you could face the issue as listed above.